# Looking for program similar to ffprobe to interrogate images?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I need to probe a lot of images from a command line to see if they will open.

ffprobe is brilliant for multimedia but can anyone steer me in the direction of a similar process I can use for images and if the universe is answering my prayers for pdfs and documents

thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `ffprobe` for images too.

Comment: LordNeckbeard The files are either corrupted or damaged. Fully aware that ffprobe works on images I am liking for an alternative especially for pdfs

Comment: possibly jhove? You can also ask on this new beta stack exchange site: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I can think of for "ffprobe for images" is ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Just like ffprobe, except you use `identify`. It tells you thinks like size, format, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use `file`:

```
$ file rooster.jpg 
rooster.jpg: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.21

$ file -b testsrc.png
PNG image data, 320 x 240, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced

$ file insulated_concrete_forms.pdf 
insulated_concrete_forms.pdf : PDF document, version 1.4
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also [`mediainfo`](https://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo), which does a good job on detecting media file formats.

**Image**

```
$ mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full some.jpg
{
"media": {
"@ref": "/path/to/some.jpg",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"ImageCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "jpg",
"Format": "JPEG",
"FileSize": "816218",
"StreamSize": "0",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2019-01-06 20:25:24",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2019-01-06 21:25:24"
},
{
"@type": "Image",
"Format": "JPEG",
"Width": "4050",
"Height": "1350",
"ColorSpace": "YUV",
"ChromaSubsampling": "4:4:4",
"BitDepth": "8",
"Compression_Mode": "Lossy",
"StreamSize": "816218",
"extra": {
"ColorSpace_ICC": "RGB"
}
}
]
}
}
```

**PDF:**

```
$ mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full some.pdf
{
"media": {
"@ref": "/path/to/some.pdf",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"TextCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "pdf",
"Format": "PDF",
"Format_Version": "1.3",
"FileSize": "141415",
"StreamSize": "141415",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2019-01-24 08:50:21",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2019-01-24 09:50:21"
},
{
"@type": "Text",
"Format": "PDF"
}
]
}
}
```

**Image File with wrong suffix:**

```
$ mediainfo --Output=JSON --Full i-am-a-jpeg.pdf
{
"media": {
"@ref": "/path/to/i-am-a-jpeg.pdf",
"track": [
{
"@type": "General",
"ImageCount": "1",
"FileExtension": "pdf",
"Format": "JPEG",
"FileSize": "816218",
"StreamSize": "0",
"File_Modified_Date": "UTC 2019-01-06 20:25:24",
"File_Modified_Date_Local": "2019-01-06 21:25:24",
"extra": {
"FileExtension_Invalid": "h3d jpeg jpg jpe jps mpo"
}
},
{
"@type": "Image",
"Format": "JPEG",
"Width": "4050",
"Height": "1350",
"ColorSpace": "YUV",
"ChromaSubsampling": "4:4:4",
"BitDepth": "8",
"Compression_Mode": "Lossy",
"StreamSize": "816218",
"extra": {
"ColorSpace_ICC": "RGB"
}
}
]
}
}
```